# Running 64-bit Windows and Linux in 32-bit mode

Tags: operating-system, 64-bit, portability, 32-bit, emulation

I need to test my C code for 32- and 64-bit versions of Windows (XP and 7) and Linux. But I have got access only to their 64-bit installations.

**Question:**  Is it possible to use some boot-time settings or other hacks to run/emulate these OSes in 32-bit mode? **If not**, is there any other way to test the portability of my C code?

Note: The C code in question is not a full-fledged application but rather a .dll/.so file.

Comment: Windows 7, at least, will run 32-bit apps in 32-bit mode. And since your "app" is a DLL, only a 32-bit app will run it anyway. I'm not sure about XP or Linux, though, as I've not interacted with 64-bit modes for either.

Comment: Well, all modern Linux distibutions also have multiarch support. This support actually is a set of 32-bit libraries installed side by side with their 64-bit counterparts

Comment: any 64-bit windows runs 32-bit apps/dlls in WoW64, which is a 32-bit compatibility layer

Comment: Afterall, you may setup VirtualBox VMs for required architecture and run your tests there.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Linux nor Windows 64Bit can run as 32Bit OS. Also, while you can run 32Bit executables on the 64Bit OS, it is not quite the same as running the same under a 32Bit OS. But it might work as a quick screening test. Besides, you certainly want that to work as well, right?

Your choices are full multi-boot setup, using VMs (might hide/expose bugs), being content with the emulation layer or running the other OS's on different hardware.

BTW: If you have Windows 64Bit, the license allows you to run 32Bit instead and vice versa. Anyway, you might want to check different language versions as well...